# Issue with IE asking to open or save file

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, iis-7

I have an issue where I have enabled basic authentication (the same happens with windows auth) on an IIS server and when end users try to download office files, using IE, a prompt appears asking the users to either open or save. If they select open, which is the default option, the office program then requires the user to re-enter the credentials as it is not authorised to access the files behind the basic auth. This prompt for authentication appears behind the browser window and When you enter the credentials it doesn't open.

Chrome does not have this issue as it automatically downloads. The way I see it there are two options; 1) Change the authentication method to something that allows the files to open without issue from IE or 2) Somehow force IE to save rather than ask the user what they want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is causing me a headache.

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: Not really a code issue. I don't see how it has anything to do with PHP. Since the AUTH token from IE cannot be  shared with Office products, when the remote document is opened via HTTP from Office, it must re-authenticate. Have you considered another AUTH method?

Comment: Yes I have considered an another auth method, but I am not sure which one would solve this issue. Windows authentication has the same issue.

Comment: Search for stuff involving SharePoint. It has had the same issue and I think they have a way to address it.